# how to deploy exploded folder in jboss 6.2

Tags: java, jboss6.x, ibm-sterling

Can we deploy a exploded jar/ear in jboss 6.2 ?

Desc:
I need to deploy a exploded ear file in jboss 6.2.I am able to do the same in jboss 4.2.3.
But while trying the same procedure in jboss 6.2 the standalone.bat(run.bat in jboss 4.2.3) file is not deploying my exploded ear.

Questions:
1.Is it possible to do so.
2.If yes,What should be the exploded folder name(should it be with extension .ear/ .jar)

Answer (score 0):

In standalone mode you might use the filesystem and simple drop the exploded web app to standalone/deployments,to trigger deployment you have to create marker file with name .dodeploy (ex. Demo.war.dodeploy). Fo through [documentatuion](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS72/Application+deployment) for more details